# Three lines which are intersecting a triangle

Tags: tkz-euclide

[image: three lines with arrows at both ends intersecting a triangle]

I want to draw three lines, namely l, m and n, which are cutting the triangle. It is possible that my question is very simple but I can't draw this. In fact I am able to draw three line segments with tkz-euclid. Please help me. Also, in how many ways can we draw same figures using different tools like tkz-euclid, pgfplot, asymptote?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(10,0){C}
\tkzDrawSegment(B,C)
\tkzDefPoint(5,5){A}
\tkzDrawSegment(B,A)
\tkzDrawSegment(C,A)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example using `asymptote`.

```
unitsize(1cm);

pair A = (3,5);
pair B = (0,0);
pair C = (6,0);

draw(A--B--C--cycle);

label("A", A, N);
label("B", B, SW);
label("C", C, SE);

draw((0,3)--(6,3), Arrows);
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One option with `TiKZ`

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=2mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0)--++(0:3cm)--++(120:3cm)--cycle;
\draw[<->] (0.5,2)--++(0:2cm);
\draw[<->] (0,1)--++(-60:2cm);
\draw[<->] (3,1)--++(-120:2cm);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

With `tkz-euclide` could be

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usetkzobj{all}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\tkzDefPoint(0,0){B}
\tkzDefPoint(10,0){C}
\tkzDefPoint(5,5){A}
\tkzDrawSegments(A,B B,C C,A)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](B)
\tkzLabelPoints[xshift=-10pt](C)
\tkzLabelPoints[above](A)

\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](-3,-2){A1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[A](3,-2){A2}
\tkzDrawVector[<->](A1,A2)

\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](0,2){B1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[B](3,-1){B2}
\tkzDrawVector[<->](B1,B2)

\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](0,2){C1}
\tkzDefShiftPoint[C](-3,-1){C2}
\tkzDrawVector[<->](C1,C2)
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i mean what is the correction in my code if i am using it

Comment: @snehal I've included an example with `tkz-euclide`